# Hide items from autocomplete menu in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Does anybody know how to hide specific things from this menu?

I want my columns be at number one priority, followed by functions and constants. I don't need all this system variables there.

In Visual Studio I can show those entries by category. Does a feature like this exists for the SQL Server Management Studio as well?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SSMS menu under Tools/Options, you can find that this option is not available:

[image]

One option is to type `category.` (= your table-name followed by a dot), but this defeats the use of Intellisense

Slightly better would be: `SELECT * FROM category c WHERE c.`  which should start showing the fields for this table.

Comment: "this defeats the use of Intellisense" no it doesn't, you are *supposed* to use table references or aliases, rather than just a possibly ambiguous column

Comment: @Charlieface: You are right, but more typing is to be done, and some of us are lazy ... 

Comment: When you have *multiple* tables involved, `c.ColumnName` is much fewer characters than `Category.ColumnName` @Luuk ;) Especially when you repeat that for the many columns defined in the `SELECT`.